# Cannot apt upgrade or install due to unmet dependencies error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies, apt

OS and version: Pop!_OS 21.04

Whenever I try to install a new package/upgrade, I see the following error:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.33-0ubuntu5) but 2.34-0ubuntu3 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.34-0ubuntu3) but 2.33-0ubuntu5 is installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.34)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Things I have tried:
**1. apt --fix-broken install**

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.33-0ubuntu5) but 2.34-0ubuntu3 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.34-0ubuntu3) but 2.33-0ubuntu5 is installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.34)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks; this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

**2. Following the steps of a similar post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315906/unmet-dependencies-libc6-the-package-system-is-broken**

3. sudo apt update output

```
Hit:1 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
23 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

I'm new to Linux, and am pretty stuck at the moment. Any help would be tremendous. Thanks!

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.