# How to fix unmet dependencies after running 'sudo apt update'?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

The output of running `sudo apt <package>` is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sg3-utils : Depends: libsgutils2-1.46-2 (>= 1.46) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Referring to similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483981/cannot-apt-upgrade-or-install-due-to-unmet-dependencies-error), I have run the following commands:

- `sudo apt install -f` to fix broken install

However, when I run `sudo apt install <package>`, the output remains the same:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sg3-utils : Depends: libsgutils2-1.46-2 (>= 1.46) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The suggested solution of fixing the unmet dependencies using `apt --fix-broken install` does not work.

Please share a solution.

Comment: What initial package(s) are you trying to install? What's the output of `apt-cache search libsgutils2-1`?